# Get data from div classes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How I can get data from div classes?

```
Example: A <div class=ab>1 &nbsp; 2</div>b <div class=ab>3 &nbsp; 4</div>c.
```

I want: `1 &nbsp; 2`, `3 &nbsp; 4` etc - between `<div class=ab>` and `</div>`.

```
Second example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt29747">
```

I want: `tt29747` - between `http://www.imdb.com/title/` and `">`.

With **strstr** all good, except that I get only the first result. I tried some solutions founded here but no succes, regular expressions beyond me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing the HTML using [DOMDocument()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of regex.

However, here is the regex to parse assuming there will be no nested `div`:

```
$html= 'Example: Lorem <div class=ab>1 &nbsp; 2</div>ipsum <div class=ab>3 &nbsp; 4</div>dolor.';
preg_match_all('|<div class=ab>([^<]*)</div>|i', $html, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

And for parsing the title id:

```
$html = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt29747">';
preg_match('|imdb.com/title/(tt\d+)|i', $html, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Comment: Its in `$m[1][0]` May be you are looking it at `$m[1][1]`!

Comment: Your last comment says its `"ab"` with quotes, where in code its only `ab`. May be this is the reason? Just run the code as it is I have shown in example. See how it returns. :-)

Comment: From my code above: replace the line with this one `$html = '<div class=abTHIS><div class=ab>1 &nbsp; 2</div></div>';` and run my code. It works!

Comment: I don't know. May be I am not getting what you mean! Did you do a `print_r($m);` after the matching? And checked what it has? You can update your question with your sample code that you are trying right now.